# PlayFramework 2.5 - Ebean update using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, playframework, orm, ebean

I'm developing a website with an inline editor using Play framework 2.5 and Ebean as ORM, and I have a news section where the admin can edit every single news (editing fields inline such as title, content and so on).
In order to do so, I set every html element which can be modified with an id equals to the news model field (e.g. the html element mapping the field title will have id="title"), then when I receive data from the client, I use reflection on the controller to map every content with the correct news field.

Here is the code (EditContent is an object which contains informations like the id and the htmlContent of every modified content):

```
News news = News.find.byId(newsId);

for(EditContent content : pageContents.contents) {
    Field field = news.getClass().getField(content.cssId);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(news, content.htmlContent);
}

news.update();
```

The problem is that the update seems to be executed, but actually values are not updated on db. Using debugger, I inspected the object news and I can see that the fields are modified properly, but then the update has no effects on db.
Also, I noticed that the same code using:

```
News news = new News()
...
//reflection to save modifed contents in the new object
...
news.save()
```

works as I expect, saving a new row in the database.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why do you need to use reflection? Also, as you are changing a EditContent object, havre you tried to save it instead of news?

Comment: I want to use reflection in order to avoid to explicitly set every news field (and to edit the code controller in case I change the model). I cannot save EditContent because is only a subset of the news fields, in particular it contains only modified fields, also it contains other informations relative to html, such as cssId

Comment: Hi @lbaggi, how did you solve the problem? Is it even possible to make it work with reflections? I would really appreciate your response, because i am having the exact same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the field values rather than calling a setter method.

So for the update()  ... Ebean is not aware of which properties have been changed - it thinks none have changed.

Play modifies field put calls into method calls via enhancement. So this is possibly why you think these reflection field set values might work.

Comment: In other words, there is no way to update an Entity using reflection? I have to set every field directly (and let Ebean handle its generated getters/setters)?
Why instead the insertion of a new entity works?

Comment: > In other words, there is no way to update an Entity using reflection? ... No. What it means is that Ebean intercepts methods (setters) and that you can't intercept reflection field set.

Comment: Do you realise that Ebean expects getters and setters (well, methods). It is Play that has promoted the use of public fields ... and the Play enhancement that converts those public field getfield/putfield calls into method calls ... it is Play doing that, not Ebean.

Comment: Does your News entity bean have methods or public fields?  I presume it has public fields ... as that has been promoted by Play.

Comment: The News entity bean will also have methods (some added by Play - effectively getters and setters and some by Ebean enhancement).  If you use reflection to call those setter methods ...

Comment: Yes, I use public fields as promoted by Play (my fault, I was remembering wrong about generated getters/setters promoter). Anyway, now it is all clear, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No problem (and yes it is very confusing unfortunately). BTW: insert new entity works because ... it doesn't care which properties are dirty - they are all considered dirty for insert.  For update, Ebean is detecting which properties are dirty.  NB: There is also the option of using Transaction.setUpdateAllLoadedProperties(true) ... where the update includes loaded rather than dirty properties.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, as @Rob Bygrave said... The setter method should be invoked here rather than setting the field value directly cause the ebean will ignore the new value if you set the value to the corresponding field directly. It seems that the play framework following the Java bean convention, so basically we can guess what the set name called.
Here is an example code to update User's information dynamically:

`private final String[] userUpdatableNames = { "name", "password", "allowGPS" };`

...

```
        JsonNode dateForm = request().body().asJson();
        Field field;
        Class<?> type;
        Method method;      
        for (int i = 0; i < userUpdatableNames.length; i++) {
            if (isArgs[i]) {
                        try {
                            field = target.getClass().getDeclaredField(userUpdatableNames[i]);
                            type = field.getType();
                            Method method = target.getClass().getMethod("set" + initialUpperize(userUpdatableNames[i]), type);
                            method.invoke(target, convert(type,dateForm.findValue(userUpdatableNames[i]).textValue()));
                            }catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException
| NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                            return internalServerError(Json.toJson("Invoke exception"));
                           }
            } 
      }
```

...

```
public String initialUpperize(String str) {
    return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
}
```

...

```
private Object convert(Class<?> targetType, String text) {
    PropertyEditor editor = PropertyEditorManager.findEditor(targetType);
    editor.setAsText(text);
    return editor.getValue();
}
```

where isArgs is a boolean array to mark whether the field is in Json body...

Thanks